# Shell scripting : Change in input stream not working as desired

Tags: command-line, scripts

I'm trying to create a shell script that can count words and lines in a file. (yes, I know you can do that using wc, but just for the sake of learning loops)

Code

```sh
echo "enter filename"
read f
if [ -s $f ]
then
    terminal=`tty`

    exec < $f

    nol=0
    now=0

    while read line
    do
        nol=`expr $nol + 1`
        set $line
        now=`expr $now + $#`
    done

    echo "No.of lines in the file =$nol"
    echo "No.of words in the file =$now"

    exec < $terminal
fi
```

expected output:

```
No.of lines in the file =3
No.of words in the file =166
```

Actual output:

```
$ sh wc.sh 
enter filename
spock.txt
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE='xim'
COLORTERM='gnome-terminal'
COMPIZ_BIN_PATH='/usr/bin/'
COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE='ubuntu'
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS='unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-PfcwnNxO9c'
DEFAULTS_PATH='/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path'
DESKTOP_SESSION='ubuntu'
DISPLAY=':0'
...
XDG_MENU_PREFIX='gnome-'
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR='/run/user/1000'
XDG_SEAT='seat0'
XDG_SEAT_PATH='/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
XDG_SESSION_ID='c1'
XDG_SESSION_PATH='/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
XDG_VTNR='7'
XMODIFIERS='@im=ibus'
_='/bin/sh'
f='spock.txt'
line=''
nol='2'
now='66'
terminal='/dev/pts/0'
No.of lines in the file =3
No.of words in the file =166
```

Could anyone clarify what I'm doing wrong?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably for the last line, or somewhere in between, there's an empty line. When you run `set` without arguments, it prints every variable set in the current shell. [From the POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set):

> If no options or arguments are specified, set shall write the names and values of all shell variables in the collation sequence of the current locale.

This will throw off your calculation, since this does not set the arguments to the empty list - you'll be adding the previous line's word count again.

You're getting that output because `$line` is empty, so what you should do is check if it is, in fact, empty:

```
while read line
do
    nol=`expr $nol + 1`
    if [ -n "$line" ]
    then
        set $line
        now=`expr $now + $#`
    fi
done
```

---

Aside from that, instead of `exec <$f`, I'd suggest using:

```
while read ..
do 
    ...
done < "$f"
```

What your doing now is:

```
terminal=`tty`
exec < $f    
...
exec < $terminal
```

You are redirecting the whole script, whereas you only need the redirection for the loop. You can skip the call to `tty` and the two `exec`s:

```
if [ -s $f ]
then
    nol=0
    now=0

    while read line
    do
        ...
    done < "$f"
    ...
fi
```

---

And use [arithmetic expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) instead of command substitution with `expr`:

```
nol=$((nol + 1))
now=$((now + $#))
```

---

And always, *always*, quote  your variables unless you explicitly want splitting:

- `[ -s "$f" ]`
- `exec < "$f"`

Consider what happens when `f` contains spaces:

```
f="there are spaces in this filename"
[ -s $f ]
exec < $f
```

You'll get errors, because once `$f` is replaced by its contents, each word in it will be seen separately:

```
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: $f: ambiguous redirect
```

Comment: thanks. I have few other questions
-what did you mean by "splitting" in the last part. Could you explain that again?

Comment: also, I cannot understand why I would need the : 
done < "$f"
I wrote another script : http://pastebin.com/kj1aNg5q

this gives the desired output in spite of using the same format here.

Comment: @TheWiz see update.

Comment: thanks. could you answer my second comment above please. Also, I tried it your way. I still see the same output. http://pastebin.com/eCtjgwY6
@muru

Comment: @TheWiz The redirection has nothing to do with the output you get. You're getting that output because `$line` is empty, so what you should do is check if it is, in fact empty.

Comment: oh damn! that is it! that is everything I wanted to know! The blank lines made the whole output obscure. I feel stupid. I cleared the blank lines and now its good. Thank you so much @muru.

Comment: can you tell me how I can express this in arithmetic expressions?
now=`expr $now + $#`  @muru

Comment: @TheWiz `now=$((now + $#))`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21881/discussion-between-thewiz-and-muru).